# How can install bestNormalize package for R?

Tags: r

```
install.packages("bestNormalize")
devtools::install_github("petersonR/bestNormalize")
```

I am trying to install the bestNormalize package for R, but i have the following ERROR:

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> also installing the dependencies ‘tibble’, ‘cli’, ‘clock’, ‘hardhat’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’, ‘recipes’
>
> There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
> binary source needs_compilation
> tibble         3.1.6  3.1.8              TRUE
> cli            3.2.0  3.6.0              TRUE
> clock          0.6.0  0.6.1              TRUE
> hardhat        0.2.0  1.2.0             FALSE
> lifecycle      1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE
> rlang          1.0.2  1.0.6              TRUE
> tidyselect     1.1.2  1.2.0             FALSE
> vctrs          0.4.1  0.5.2              TRUE
> recipes        0.2.0  1.0.4             FALSE
> bestNormalize  1.8.2  1.8.3             FALSE
>
> Binaries will be installed
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/tibble_3.1.6.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 872395 bytes (851 KB)
> downloaded 851 KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 1255499 bytes (1.2 MB)
> downloaded 1.2 MB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/clock_0.6.0.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 3387600 bytes (3.2 MB)
> downloaded 3.2 MB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_1.0.2.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 1718546 bytes (1.6 MB)
> downloaded 1.6 MB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/vctrs_0.4.1.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 1569486 bytes (1.5 MB)
> downloaded 1.5 MB
>
> package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> Warning in install.packages :
> cannot remove prior installation of package ‘tibble’
> Warning in install.packages :
> problem copying C:\Users\Alex\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\tibble\libs\x64\tibble.dll to C:\Users\Alex\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\tibble\libs\x64\tibble.dll: Permission denied
> Warning in install.packages :
> restored ‘tibble’
> package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> Warning in install.packages :
> cannot remove prior installation of package ‘cli’
> Warning in install.packages :
> problem copying C:\Users\Alex\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\Alex\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
> Warning in install.packages :
> restored ‘cli’
> package ‘clock’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> Warning in install.packages :
> cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
> Warning in install.packages :
> problem copying C:\Users\Alex\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\Alex\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
> Warning in install.packages :
> restored ‘rlang’
> package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> Warning in install.packages :
> cannot remove prior installation of package ‘vctrs’
> Warning in install.packages :
> problem copying C:\Users\Alex\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll to C:\Users\Alex\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll: Permission denied
> Warning in install.packages :
> restored ‘vctrs’
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8YzMvr\downloaded_packages
> installing the source packages ‘hardhat’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘recipes’, ‘bestNormalize’
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/hardhat_1.2.0.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 953223 bytes (930 KB)
> downloaded 930 KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB)
> downloaded 104 KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyselect_1.2.0.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 101498 bytes (99 KB)
> downloaded 99 KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/recipes_1.0.4.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 801878 bytes (783 KB)
> downloaded 783 KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/bestNormalize_1.8.3.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1129792 bytes (1.1 MB)
> downloaded 1.1 MB
>
> installing *source* package 'hardhat' ...
> package 'hardhat' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> using staged installation
> R
> data
> moving datasets to lazyload DB
> inst
> byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
> namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.3 is required
> Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
> Ejecución interrumpida
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'hardhat'
> removing 'C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/hardhat'
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘hardhat’ had non-zero exit status
> installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
> package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
> removing 'C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
> restoring previous 'C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
> installing *source* package 'tidyselect' ...
> package 'tidyselect' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
> removing 'C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/tidyselect'
> restoring previous 'C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/tidyselect'
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependency 'hardhat' is not available for package 'recipes'
> removing 'C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/recipes'
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
> Warning in read.dcf(file.path(p, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Version")) :
> cannot open file 'C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/recipes/DESCRIPTION': it is a directory
> ERROR: dependency 'recipes' is not available for package 'bestNormalize'
> removing 'C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/bestNormalize'
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘bestNormalize’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8YzMvr\downloaded_packages’
> Warning message:
> In readLines(file, skipNul = TRUE) :
> cannot open file 'C:/Users/Alex/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/recipes/DESCRIPTION': it is a directory

I would like to install bestNormalized!

Many thanks

Comment: I would suggest updating "rtools" as the error centralizes around incorrect version of rtools (first line of the error message) and potentially updating R.

Comment: You should install [RTools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). However, another issue here is that R is not able to remove older versions of the packages it is updating. This commonly happens if the packages are loaded. Easiest thing is to quit R, navigate in Windows Explorer to the directory `"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\"` and delete all folders which begin with `"00LOCK"`. Then enter a vanilla R session (i.e. not RStudio) and try again to `install.packages("bestNormalize")`.